# Unix: how to check how many times would digit 3 appear from 1 to 1232

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

Can anyone tell me how to do it?
My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i count=0;
for ((i=1;i<=1232;i++));
do
if [                             ]; then
count=count+1; 
fi
done
echo $count
```

`333` counts as one occurrence.

Comment: Would 333 count as one case or 3 cases?

Comment: It would count as one case. I was trying to use grep

Comment: I can do it in one line, but if this is homework I don't want to just post an answer.

Comment: "Count how many decimal numbers between 1 and 1232 (inclusive) have at least one 3 in their expression?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i count=0;
for ((i=1;i<=1232;i++));
do
    if [[ "$i" =~ .*3.* ]]; then
        count=count+1 
    fi
done
echo $count
```

This code performs a regex searching for `3` in `i` as the `for` loop progresses.

Incidentally, the answer is 315.

If you need to use `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i count=0;
for ((i=1;i<=1232;i++));
do
    if grep -q 3 <<<$i; then
        count=count+1 
    fi
done
echo $count
```

It's a lot slower, though.

Comment: @user3105629 Yes. I edited my question. However, it is quite a bit slower than the standard regex I posted.

Comment: I still don't get the (grep -q 3 <<<$i ). 
I am sorry

Comment: Don't worry about it. What don't you understand about the `grep` statement? :)

Comment: I understand grep -q 3 but not <<<$i

Comment: The `<<<` expands $i and pipes it to `grep`'s stdin. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) for more info.

Comment: Did *you* try it? `count=count+1` will set `$count` to the string "count+1".

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes. The program works fine for me. What about you?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that `typeset -i count=0` affects the behavior that way. Time to read the bash documentation again!

Comment: @KeithThompson No problem. I guess you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

To count how many numbers from 1 to 1232 have at least one `3` in their decimal representations (so `333` is counted once):

```
$ seq 1232 | grep -c 3
315
```

To count the total number of `3`s (so `333` is counted 3 times):

```
$ seq 1232 | sed 's/./& /g' | fmt -w 1 | grep -c 3
346
```